# How to import module?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have controller homeController where i do `export let index`

```
import { Request, Response } from "express";
  export let index = (req: Request, res: Response) => {
     console.log("home");
 };
```

In app.ts

```
  import * as homeController from "../src/modules/home/controllers/home.controller";
  const app = express();
  ...
   app.get("/", homeController.index);
```

tslint passed it but whe i do npm start (npm run serve), i getting the error

```
 internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:589
  throw err;
   ^
 Error: Cannot find module '../src/modules/home/controllers/home.controller'
```

path to /home.controller is right

Comment: shouldn't it be homeController instead of home.controller ?

Comment: If relative path is giving you trouble, use path module to give the absolute path in require function.

Comment: Can you try `import { index } from "../src/modules/home/controllers/home.controller";`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in your HomeController you are exporting a function, the index function. So, when you import that file you are already importing the function so

```
import * as homeController from "../src/modules/home/controllers/home.controller";
  const app = express();
  ...
   app.get("/", homeController);
```

might work

If you want to do homeController.index

In you homeController module you should do

```
import { Request, Response } from "express";
let index = (req: Request, res: Response) => {
 console.log("home");
};

module.exports = {
    index
}
```